# while loading image on button click using update process it allows other buttons click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Inside update panel I have 40 buttons: Button1, Button2, Button3 etc

On each button click, text will be stored to a variable as below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text1="You clicked button1";
    }
```

When I click on Button1 the ajax gif inside updateprocess will start but at the same time it allows other buttons to be clicked.

How do I prevent it?

Else is there any other way to do so other than using updateprocess?

Comment: Just like that `Button2.Enabled = false;`?

Comment: On button click..? If yes, after the Button1 is clicked and text is stored I want the rest of the buttons to be enabled. @SelimYıldız

Comment: Exactly, do you want to also set enable of all these buttons after click function is done, right?

Comment: Yes @SelimYıldız

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now. I have added an answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion we had in comments, if I understood you correctly you can use [`OnClientClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick) to disable buttons when user clicked in client side. After click function is completed you can enable all of these buttons from server side.

Client side:

```
<script>
    function DisableButtons() {
        $("#<%=btn1.ClientID %>").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#<%=btn2.ClientID %>").attr('disabled', true);
        //other buttons
    }

</script>

<asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="Button 1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click" OnClientClick="DisableButtons();"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
<asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="Button 2" runat="server" OnClick="btn2_Click" OnClientClick="DisableButtons();"  UseSubmitBehavior="false"  />
<%--Other buttons--%>
```

Note that you need to add [`UseSubmitBehavior="false"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior)  as well to buttons.

Server side:

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //other processes
    SetButtonsEnable();
}

protected void SetButtonsEnable()
{
    btn1.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
    btn2.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
    //other buttons
}
```